# FancyBox image grouping

Tags: jquery, fancybox, gallery, grouping

I am using the latest Fancybox and I am trying to have multiple galleries on one page.  I tried the `rel` attribute for grouping and the example below.  No matter the photos are not grouping.  I've tried all the recommendations I have seen in the forums to no avail. I tried this snippet as a script in the page and it didn't work either:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();

<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="cover" href="images/horse1L.jpg"></a>
```

Any help you can provide would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the following lines from my script.js file allowed the rel attributes to work correctly:

`$('.list4>li>figure>a, .list6>li>figure>a').attr('rel','appendix') .prepend('<span class="sitem_over"><strong></strong></span>')`

Answer (score 0):

This structure using `rel` like

```
<p> Gallery one</p>
<a rel="gallery01" class="fancybox" href="one_01.jpg">Gallery one / image 01</a>
<a rel="gallery01" class="fancybox" href="one_02.jpg">Gallery one / image 02</a>

<p>Gallery two</p>
<a rel="gallery02" class="fancybox" href="two_01.jpg">Gallery two / image 01</a>
<a rel="gallery02" class="fancybox" href="two_02.jpg">Gallery two / image 02</a>
```

... with this script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox(); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

... should work!!

Check this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k7e3n/)** and compare it with your code.

Also make sure you updated both, js and css fancybox files to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks JFK, for some reason the template I am using will not jive with these changes.  I see in the fiddle it is quite simply apparent, but still no go. I reconfirmed all my js and css fancybox files are current as well as updating to the jquery used in the fiddle.

Comment: Could you share a link? also make sure that you are loading a single version of jQuery, ideally the latest (some templates or other plugins may include their own jQuery version)

Comment: I uploaded but I'm a tad hesitant to share the domain name and I know there is no PM on stackoverflow.  I'm poking the template support people, along with what fancybox has provided along with yourself, it's not working right and that a custom script maybe the culprit.  When I start trimming scripts due to my naivety I see drastic changes.  Big thanks JFK for your reply.

Comment: you can send a private link?

Comment: @user1956181 check my profile and go from there to my website and use the contact form to send it

Comment: I sent it to your site contact form and don't have enough points to chat on stack.  I have centered on gallery 3 for troubleshooting.  Big thanks JFK.

Comment: @user1956181 I am afraid I did not receive anything. Did you send it using the contact form in my website?

Comment: With the help of template support I found that removing the following lines from my script.js file allowed the rel attributes to work correctly:                                                                                       `$('.list4>li>figure>a, .list6>li>figure>a').attr('rel','appendix')
.prepend('<span class="sitem_over"><strong></strong></span>')`